# Is it possible to add apple-app-site-association-app file to a nested directory instead of the root directory?

Tags: ios, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

there are these steps from the apple developer page:

> Adding support for universal links is easy. There are three steps you need to take:
>
> Create an apple-app-site-association file that contains JSON data about the URLs that your app can handle.
>
> Upload the apple-app-site-association file to your HTTPS web server. You can place the file at the root of your server or in the .well-known subdirectory.
>
> Prepare your app to handle universal links.

So I see "You can place the file at the root of your server or in the .well-known subdirectory." is acceptable, but what about other directories and how would I make that work?

I ask because my domain website uses a nested directory to place an independent react app within the website. PreferablyI would be able to handle the Universal Linking documents here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Those are the only two places that the site association file can exist. If you control the server then you are able to put the file there. If you don't control the server then you don't really want to trust whoever does control the server to mess with your universal links.